# How to show that this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I found in a book the following exercise:

> Show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sin\left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1}\right)$$ converges.

At first sight, I tried to break the fraction and rewrite the series as $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sin\left(n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

This actually behaves (almost) like $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sin(n)+C$$ where $$C=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n+1}$$
How can this series converge? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It cannot converge, right? If $\sum_n a_n$ converges then $a_n \to 0$, which does not happen here.

Comment: @user58955 so, the exercise is wrong obviously ?

Comment: I would be very surprised if this series actually converged, as it would mean that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 0,$$ which would be very surprising, given that $\{\sin(n)|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[-1, 1]$...

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas from what book this exercise comes from?

Comment: @Masacroso from "Analysis I" by prof. Pantelidis. It was given to me when I was undergraduate and I gave it a look yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=0$$
We have
$$\sin\left(n+1+\tfrac{1}{n+2}\right)=\sin\left(n+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\cos\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+2}-\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)+\cos\left(n+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\sin\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+2}-\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right) $$
Since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(n+\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)=0 \\
\cos\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+2}-\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\to\cos(1)\\
\sin\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n+2}-\tfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\to\sin(1)\ne 0$$
it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=0 $$
However,
$$\sin^2\left(n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\cos^2\left(n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1 $$
and we get a contradiction. Therefore, the limit of the summand is not $0$, and the series diverges.